# Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-1

I got this error: `ERROR/MapActivity(258): Couldn't get connection factory client`

Everything worked fine, it's all of a sudden, how come that happens?
I know my api key is fine, because one month I've been using it perfectly.
How come all of a sudden it doesn't show me the map activity, and posts that error in the logcat?

Comment: Do you have network connectivity in your emulator/device?

Comment: i'm also having the same problem all of sudden this not working,and i cannot find any help for this,if any one have fix this please let me know.

Comment: Just started experiencing this yesterday.  Made a small change to my app and uploaded it to my phone and now the map acts like it has an invalid key!  It should be noted that my debug key works fine.  My production key (used in multiple apps works until the particular app is rebuilt).

Comment: well i checked the log for network connection , it says
MapActivity : handling network change notification :CONNECTED

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm getting the same problem when using getFromLocationName, with a 'java.io.IOException:Service not Available' error.

I've done a bit of googling around and it seems this is a bug in the software.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

Comment: I am facing the same problem with google api with api 7. What is the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: hey madcabbage , there is no solution in your link, for "Couldn't get connection factory client",  what is the solution for this error ?

Comment: Seems to be a solution (aka work around) in the posted bug link.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816#c21

Comment: I had this error when first trying to use the MapView. I didn't have the proper permissions: 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 16):

I had reinstalled Android dev kit on my new system and the debug.keystore had changed.
Once I used the keytool to make a new MD5 and registered that with Google I was back in action with a fresh apiKey.

"Couldn't get connection factory client" is a weird message for an invalid apiKey !

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem with the API Key. Do I have to reinstall Android dev Kid? Do you know how to generate a new debug.keystore? Thanks!

Comment: I think this might help: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-mapview-generate-api-key-using-java-keytool/

Comment: Someone Somewhere is great and made my day ;-p worked perfectly indeed !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with API level 8 on both emulator and a physical device (2.2) Actually, for me it never worked. Then by chance I tried on emulator API level 10 (with Google API of course), and it worked just fine.

*(Before that, I got a new MD5 with the keytool in order to register for a new apikey. However, I got exactly the same as the first time! Maybe I didn't use the keytool correctly.)*

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but nothing useful in the Logcat output to determine the AV.

I simply cleaned my project in Eclipse and then I got a proper stack trace of the problem, which was nothing related to MapView. It was just that the MapView was based in the first activity visible.