# Android MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I got a error when create a sample application for mapview..Couldn't get connection factory client.. Pls give me a resolution for tis..

Comment: please post your question clearly to get quick response.

Comment: I also get that, just ignore it. Do you get any tiles displayed ?

Comment: Things you should also check : Connected to the Internet, Google Maps API Key set correctly ? What does LogCat say, any exceptions ? I've had my share of problems running a HelloWord MapView, it was frustrating. I said ignore it before since it's a known bug (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816), via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Comment: I am also getting the same exception and got no solution.