# Maps not working on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi
I'm using google maps, and they work on the emulator but not on the real device.

To be clear, I did switch the apikey before creating the apk in eclipse to match the nondebug keystore used to sign the apk.  I'm doing the signing with eclipse.
The app is setup for Google APIs[Android 1.6] and it's being tested on a phone motorola atrix 4g running android 2.2

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please paste your LogCat window (Eclipse) or `adb logcat` (Console) output here and we can look for clues in that.

Comment: is there anyway of getting that without hooking up the real device to my machine?

Comment: 04-10 06:30:25.039: WARN/josh(18425): Start Point: 40727660; -73815880
04-10 06:30:25.039: WARN/josh(18425): End Point: 40725275; -73820797
04-10 06:30:25.099: INFO/MapActivity(18425): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-10 06:30:25.099: ERROR/MapActivity(18425): Couldn't get connection factory client04-10 06:30:27.349: DEBUG/dalvikvm(18425): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7835 objects / 569524 bytes in 32ms
04-10 06:30:27.429: WARN/josh(18425): onDirectionsAvailable
04-10 06:30:27.439: INFO/dalvikvm(18425): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192

Answer (score 0):

The thing that stands out from your log is the error `Couldn't get connection factory client`.

I think you've run into an Android problem. There's discussion of it here [Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

Comment: is there anyway around the problem? i can't imagine that there's no way to use google maps in 2.2