# MapActivity error couldnt connect?

Tags: android, google-maps

Every time i run my map activity class. This is the error i get.

`07-14 10:37:14.980: ERROR/MapActivity(31492): Couldn't get connection factory client`

I retrieved my api key twice so nothing is wrong with that. I dont know what the problem is. 
If anyone can help please do.

Comment: What android version are you using? and more importantly, what version of SDK are you using?

Comment: I trying to run it on honeycomb and it does this. It works on regular phones though. everything lower than honeycomb. I emailed the apk to my self and it worked on my cell phone. when i run it on my tablet it doesnt.

Comment: Well put up the source and I can try it on a Galaxy Tab 10, also the answer by Nicholas in the link he provided said that @yoshi24 the first answer at the linked question has to do with geocoding, look at the second answer for that persons problem was --> "Once I used the keytool to make a new MD5 and registered that with Google I was back in action with a fresh apiKey."

Comment: Also my own map application works fine on honeycomb so something else must be in play here

Comment: It worked all of a sudden. I ran it on my cell phone and then on honeycomb and it worked.

Comment: I'm working on a 14 app and my debug key from previous apps fails with this error. I noticed that the MD5 key has a new datestamp in the debug.keystore since my R20 install. I regenned the debug key and the problem disappeared. Haven't genned a release key yet...

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client) contains your same error, and suggests that there is a bug in the Android, with a link to a Google code issue tracker issue for Android.