# Android Google Map Api 2.3.3 does not work on a real phone

Tags: android, dictionary

I had a map application which works at all emulators. But when I tried the application on android 2.3.3 phone the map view did not appear. The application works but it does not download the map. What can the problem be?

thanks

Comment: API key? do you exporting your apk with debug key or reqular one ?

Comment: ı have a api key and i have also get a different api key but it did not work

Comment: you need to provide us logcat's logs from device ... connect device to PC with USB cable and start app with eclipse on device not emulator

Comment: i had tried that also it does not work. if you have 2.3.3 device can you try my application it is also at market.   https://market.android.com/details?id=com.javacodegeeks.android.googlemaps&feature=search_result

Comment: `08-16 14:16:49.789: ERROR/MapActivity(5209): Couldn't get connection factory client` ... and then `08-16 14:16:58.609: WARN/System.err(5209): IOException processing: 26
08-16 14:16:58.609: WARN/System.err(5209): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
08-16 14:16:58.609: WARN/System.err(5209):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)`

Comment: then google+Couldn't get connection factory client+ERROR/MapActivity and we got this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client