# couldn't get connection factory client tiles loaded android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to load google maps but I keep getting "couldn't get connection factory client. The map loads so I am assuming the key is correct but thats all I can do. The zoom controls won't load at all, and I can't move the map at all.

```
package com.saff.maps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


public class gpsActivityTest extends MapActivity{
private MapController mMapController;
private GeoPoint mGeoPoint; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapView mMapView = new MapView(this, "033wSZETHVmHYoRTPurperVQKTS8-zCsTzcbcaA");
    setContentView(mMapView);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapController = mMapView.getController();
    LocationManager mLocation= (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocation.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new updateHandler());
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public class updateHandler implements LocationListener{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    mGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    mMapController.animateTo(mGeoPoint);
    mMapController.setCenter(mGeoPoint);

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saff.maps" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".gpsActivityTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I haven't put my api code in the xml file because I get "could't find mapViewStyle theme". I have no idea what the problem is as surely I would not have this problem if my api key is correct

I have googled extensively but that does not answer my question as I have no other errors other than that here is my logCat:

```
02-10 00:10:26.305: I/Zygote(721): Zygote: pid 721 has INTERNET permission, then set capability for CAP_NET_RAW
02-10 00:10:27.135: I/ApplicationPackageManager(721): cscCountry is not German : H3G
02-10 00:10:31.145: I/MapActivity(721): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
02-10 00:10:31.145: E/MapActivity(721): Couldn't get connection factory client
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#10100
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): Has been inactive!  Starting fresh
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): focusIn: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): checkFocus: view=null next=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0 restart=true
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0
02-10 00:10:31.145: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@47e2c870 ic=null
02-10 00:10:31.175: V/InputMethodManager(721): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0 ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@47e2c870 initial=true
02-10 00:10:31.495: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{null com.swype.android.inputmethod/.SwypeInputMethod #5}
02-10 00:10:32.265: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0
02-10 00:10:32.265: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@47d57038 ic=null
02-10 00:10:32.265: V/InputMethodManager(721): Starting input: finished by someone else (view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47de52e0 conn=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to googling a bit more before asking question.. you will find this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client) and more.