# google map was not displayed in android emulator

Tags: android, android-maps

here is the XML file :

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="0q7NUYm4bgzeXlqXtKYVPJDRWUJmt8Cu0gvbWMx"
                  android:id="@+id/map_view"
                 />
```

and Manifest file :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MapsActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and in the JAVA file :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);      
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is : Map is not displayed. 
I am facing a problem Android Emulator.

Comment: had generated your own Map key?

Comment: Are you getting any exception then please post it. And make sure that the Key that you get for Map API is up to date. And one more thing the MapKey is different for different machines...

Comment: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: Alternative for the above in easy steps....http://www.technotalkative.com/how-to-generate-google-maps-api-for-android-mapview-2/

Comment: thanks for your responses

Errors  : 

Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: @user1161960, for that you please refer this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Comment: One more thing that i found is that you are trying to use built in zoom controls right. For that you need to set  android:clickable="true" in the mapview in xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you change in manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application

    <activity
      .....
    </activity>
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>
```

Comment: no dear it's not working ..
actually only the grid section is diaplayed but the map was disappear

Answer (score 0):

> Download the following APKs

[com.android.vending-1.apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3blse4z3l2et96/com.google.android.gms-6413100ccfca460007fdc988b1363db8.apk)

[com.google.android.gms-1.apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jiban3pq2cgkvo/com.android.vending-108b71f4793186b8fd1768a9cd19bbd5.apk)

> Install these two APK into your running (target) emulator with ADB
> command:
>
> adb -e install [path-to-APK-file]