# Map on android Activity not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, logcat

I am trying  to show a map on Activity, but it's not showing, even though i declared all permissions in manifest and added google library.

Here's the logcat errors

```
    08-02 18:44:44.568: E/ActivityThread(2482): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    08-02 18:44:44.579: E/ActivityThread(2482): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    08-02 18:44:44.609: E/ActivityThread(2482): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    08-02 18:44:46.229: E/MapActivity(2482): Couldn't get connection factory client
    08-02 18:44:47.468: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2482): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add Google APIs instead of the GoogleSDK to you build path?

Comment: also make sure you have your google maps key

Comment: Follow [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) tutorial and make sure all you followed correctly.

Comment: are you extending Activity or MapActivity and running on emulator or device specify ..

Comment: @user1572022 Please read this post this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Comment: on my project build target i have google APIs, for the map key i used it on another project and it worked, the problem persist the map is not showing , i have grey grids on the emulator.
thanks for helping