# couldn't get connection factory client mapactivity android? How can i resolve it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, dictionary, android-mapview

I am using map view in my application and using Google Api 2.2 as an base sdk.but when i runs the app map view is not displaying and this error is shows in log couldn't get connection factory client so whats the problem is and how can i resolve it?

Comment: you are running in emulator or device ?

Comment: i am running in emulator

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing when I used the `MapView` class in a previous project, Googled about this message and apparently it's harmless.

My app is working just fine, and the map as well, and I still get this log message from time to time, without anything noticeable.

Some people say "you need a proper API keys/a location/a proper ItemizedOverlay/a point to center on/permission set".  I got all that and I still get the error message.  The stack trace suggest that it has nothing to do with the way I call and use the class, so I just live with it and ignore it.

The most plausible answer I found is that it's actually a bug in the class:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816
- [Couldn't get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)