# Android MapActivity "Couldn't get connection factory client"

Tags: android, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Couldn’t get connection factory client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

I try to use Android MapActivity so I created my API Key from my Debug.keystore MD5 via this link 
https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Then I set this line of code in my Manifest:

Child of Application

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

set my permission like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
```

and set MapView like this with my api key

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="MY API KEY"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

In the Java file, MapActivity, I did my code from example like this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);}
```

My code used to work fine. I could set my pin point via overlayItem but after I came back to view my code again with doing nothing with my MapActivity,it doesn't work anymore. My LogCat show me like `MapActivity "Couldn't get connection factory client"`

I get to /.android Folder and deleted my debug.keystore and gen my new API Key again from it but It still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Edit: More information, the location always be null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a solution but it work for me now. I just changed an user-permission order in AndroidManifest file from

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Just move

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to the top.

edit: OMG the problem has come back again!! This is not a solution.