# google map not working on both emulator and device

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am trying to run a simple google map but its not working its showing only map background.checked on both emulator and device.

xml file:-

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Java class

```
import android.os.Bundle; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; import
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class LocationGB extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {     
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927); 
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;
     @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)).getMap();

        if (map!=null){
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just a usual check... Did you add internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: yes other web services working fine

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2199403/2219600).. It may be a bug...

Comment: post your manifest file here............

Comment: have you verified the google map key from google developers

Comment: because there is a problem with Signature.So post manifest file

Comment: Turn on **Google Maps Android API v2** only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file you have to add:

```
<permission
  android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Like from: **your.application.package** to: **com.themontcalm.droid**

And yes if you are using

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

then remove from manifest file:

and add your api code to in manifest file also:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your_Map_Key" />
```

And in manifest file you are missing this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

so also add to this also in manifest file:

you should change **android.R.id.content** with **R.id.map** in your code

Something like:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Ok...now post your java class file

Comment: and if you are  using google map v1 then try to use Google Map V2 and enable Google Android Map V2 in your Google API COnsole..

Comment: now its throwing Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException in :-  map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)).getMap();

Comment: if you are using MapFragment class then use this:                        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

Comment: please check may map activity

Comment: try to change this:android.R.id.content with R.id.content

Comment: R.id.content not found

Comment: but in xml file what is the id for that

Comment: its really killing me now its not throwing null pointer exc but....Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: now its working .... package name was wrong in manifest file (typing mistake)... Thanks for your support...

Answer (score 2):

In order to use google Map Service,

Please visit [code.google.com](http://code.google.com)
 and get you ApiKey.

create a project there->go to services->Activate the Google Maps Android API v2.
Then Create Key for your application.

Add the following permissions to your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

use

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_apikey" />
```

also add

```
<permission
        android:name="com.anchit.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

inside your Application Tag in manifest.

Use

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
```

in your code.

and set the other required properties. Now Run the Application.

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest add

```
<permission
  android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Also add to your application tag

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your_Map_Key" />
```

You can also visit [Google Map V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) , [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) and [Example of map v2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

Hope it helps you.

**Edit:**

As per you said Add this xml file in your project

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And access it with in your map activity

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
```

Comment: If you are trying for v2 above three link is sufficient for create map in your app. @VijayLaxmi

Comment: now i am using v2 and now its throwing java.lang.NullPointerException in :- map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)).getMap();