# Google maps stopped working after app migration

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my problem:

**E/MapActivity﹕ Couldn't get connection factory client**

I do get mapView build, however no tiles, just grey background.

The thing that bugs me, that I'm compiling the same code which has an actuall production app on GPlay and Maps are working normaly.

The full story.

I got the app code some time ago, it was coded with **Eclipse/Android SDK**. Only now I needed to tweak some bits. I have imported the app into **Android Studio 1.0** and it got only one error before running. Apparently proguard is now minifyEnabled. After this fix app compiled successfully.

I'm using Genymotion as emulator, so I was faced with:

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]** aka No Google Play Services

After installing GPlay services for the emulator, everything runs fine, expect Map. It does run, just no tiles...

The API_KEY of courses exists in manifest and is a KEY for production build.

So, what I'm missing here? Why would the API_KEY which works for Google Play store not work for emulator?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Having suspicion that Genymotion/Google Play Services might be the cause, I have compiled the app directly to my Samsung S4. My Phone of cource has GPlay Services set up. However, no luck, still grey background.

Comment: I regenerated API KEY with release keystore - no luck. Have generated a release.apk still no luck... getting frustrated now...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to be the same as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client). It might be a bug with the software. Supposedly [recreating](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key) your API key might fix it.

Comment: Did not help. I have regenerated new API key using production keystore, no luck still grey backgrounds.